# Dell Vostro won't boot with a USB. When try to boot from it, it say “BOOT ERROR”

Tags: dell

Here's the problem; I'm trying to install Ubuntu:Maverick Meerkat using a USB flash drive on my dell vostro but when I try to boot from it, it say "BOOT ERROR". I used Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.0.8 to create the bootable USB flash drive. Any idea?

I tried the same process on other machines and it works fine.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with my Dell Inspiron 530.  I used "USB Startup Disk Creator" for the pen drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding the Ctrl key during boot.  Some computers have a broken BIOS that numbers the devices incorrectly, but an alternative bit of boot code to work around this exists and is activated if you hold down Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

What format did you have the USB drive in before flashing the iso? I have had trouble if the drive isn't formatted to FAT or FAT32 first.

I also like to use UNetbootin: [Download UNetbootin here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I can add that this is replicate in my Dell Insipron 530N which never boots usb pen drives made using ubuntu usb creator but does if I use an .img made in imagewriter. Dont know why and would love to fix it